# Copy items from treeview tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, treeview

I have a tree view in one of my tkinter app and i wanted to know if it really is possible to actually, just copy a selected field on right-clicking by the user. If not , is there any other widget tht allows the user to copy a selected field shown in GUI window.

Code:

```
    log = Toplevel(root)
    log.title('View all Visitors')
    log.focus_force()
    # setup treeview
    columns = (('ID', 80), ('S_ID', 80), ('S_NAME', 300), ('Title of the book', 500), ('Accession no. of 
                book', 80),
               ('Date Taken', 100), ('Due Date', 100), ('Date_Returned', 100), ('Status', 80))
    tree = ttk.Treeview(log, height=20, columns=[
                        x[0] for x in columns], show='headings')
    tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

    # setup columns attributes
    for col, width in columns:
        tree.heading(col, text=col)
        tree.column(col, width=width, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    # fetch data
    con = mysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root',
                        password='****', database='library')
    c = con.cursor()
    sql_command_1 = 'SELECT * FROM borrow;'
    c.execute(sql_command_1)

    # populate data to treeview
    for rec in c:
        tree.insert('', 'end', value=rec)

    # scrollbar
    sb = tk.Scrollbar(log, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=tree.yview)
    sb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
    tree.config(yscrollcommand=sb.set)
    a = tree.item(tree.focus())['values']

    btn = tk.Button(log, text='Close', command=out,
                    width=20, bd=2, fg='red',font=font_text)
    btn.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=E+W)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a popup menu and bind it to Button-3. Here is an example quickly built from one of my projects

```
popup1 = tk.Menu(tree, tearoff=0)
popup1.add_command(
    command=your_copy,
    label="Copy")

def your_copy():
    item = tree.selection()[0]
    log.clipboard_clear()
    log.clipboard_append(tree.item(item, option='text')

def popup_menu(event):
    tree.identify_row(event.y)
    popup1.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    
tree.bind('<Button-3>', popup_menu)
```

Comment: but how do i manage to copy the item. how do i def the function your_command to be able to copy the item from the treeview into the clipboard

Comment: @filip he has updated the code and that code probably works, if you want to see what i did, ill surely say :D

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and created a function which is quite modular.

```
import pyperclip    

def copy_from_treeview(tree, event):
    selection = tree.selection()
    column = tree.identify_column(event.x)
    column_no = int(column.replace("#", "")) - 1
            
    copy_values = []
    for each in selection:
        try:
            value = tree.item(each)["values"][column_no]
            copy_values.append(str(value))
        except:
            pass
        
    copy_string = "\n".join(copy_values)
    pyperclip.copy(copy_string)
```

Simply bind the function to ctrl + c:

```
tree.bind("<Control-Key-c>", lambda x: copy_from_treeview(tree, x))
```

Comment: thanks @TimoGH. I needed the same but for all rows/columns and found here a handy way (for later reference) https://stackoverflow.com/a/67165822/10789707

Answer (score 2):

You could try to get hold of selected rows, then work from there:

```
import pyperclip

treeview.bind("<Control-Key-c>", copy_from_treeview)

def copy_from_treeview(treeview, _):
    selections = treeview.selection()  # get hold of selected rows

    copied_string = ""
    for row in selections:
        values = treeview.item(row, 'values')  # get values for each selected row

        for item in values:
            copied_string += f"{item}  "

    pyperclip.copy(copied_string)
```