# Deleting selected treeview items from Sqlite Database

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am trying to create a database system where I can save and delete user records from both the front end (python/tkinter) and backend (sqlite). So far I have managed to get the front end to work. On button click the data (input into entry boxes) is saved to a tree. A delete button will clear the data from the tree and entry boxes.

Now I am struggling to get the backend to work. While I am able to save the data to the sqlite database, I can't figure out how to delete the items from the sqlite database when selected in the tkinter tree. Below is a snippet of the code. Note that I used a separate file for the backend named "Backend".

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import Backend

#frontend

root = Tk()

ID = StringVar()
Name= StringVar()
Age = StringVar()
BirthDate = StringVar()

def SaveData():
    if(len(ID.get())!=0):
       Backend.saveUserRec(ID.get(),Name.get(), Age.get(), BirthDate.get())
       tree.insert('', 'end', values=(ID.get(),Name.get(), Age.get(), BirthDate.get()))
    else:
        IDnumber= messagebox.showinfo ("","Please enter an ID number")

def DeleteData():
    try:
        selected_item = tree.selection()[0] ## get selected item from tree
        messageDelete= tkinter.messagebox.askyesno ("","Do you want to permanently delete this record?")
        if messageDelete > 0:
                tree.delete(selected_item)
                Clear()
                Backend.DeleteRecord()
    except Exception:
        pass

def Clear():
    ID.set("")
    Name.set("")
    Age.set("")
    BirthDate.set("")

btnSaveData = Button(ButtonFrame, text='Save', font=('arial',12), height=1, width=16, bd=2, padx=13, command=SaveData)
btnSaveData.grid(row=0,column=0)

btnDeleteData = Button(ButtonFrame, text='Delete', font=('arial',12), height=1, width=16, bd=2, padx=13, command=DeleteData)
btnDeleteData.grid(row=0,column=1)

root.mainloop()

#backend

import sqlite3

def userrecord():
    con =sqlite3.connect("userRecord.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userRecord(userid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, \
    ID text, Name text, Age text, BirthDate text)")
    con.commit()
    con.close()

def saveUserRec(ID, Name, Age, BirthDate):
    con =sqlite3.connect("userRecord.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    userrecord()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO userRecord VALUES (null, ?, ?, ?, ?)”, (ID, Name, Age, BirthDate))
    con.commit()
    con.close()

def DeleteRecord():
    con =sqlite3.connect("userRecord.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM userRecord WHERE userid=?", (userid, tree.set(selected_item, '#1')))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Comment: so u need to know how to get the selected data onto a variable i guess. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62823245/copy-items-from-treeview-tkinter) give u starting idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to delete the selected item in the treeview from the database, you need to pass the unique `userid` of the selected item to backend `DeleteRecord()` function:

```
def DeleteRecord(userid):
    con = sqlite3.connect("userRecord.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM userRecord WHERE userid = ?", (userid,))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

So how do you get the `userid` of the selected item?  Currently your code does not have the `userid` information when adding new item.  You need to return the `userid` of the newly inserted record in backend `saveUserRec()` function:

```
def saveUserRec(ID, Name, Age, BirthDate):
    con = sqlite3.connect("userRecord.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    Backend.userrecord()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO userRecord VALUES (null, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (ID, Name, Age, BirthDate))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    # return the userid of newly added record
    return cur.lastrowid
```

And update `SaveData()` to include the `userid` into treeview item via the `iid` option of `Treeview.insert()`:

```
def SaveData():
    if len(ID.get()) != 0:
       # save the record to database and get the userid for the record
       userid = Backend.saveUserRec(ID.get(), Name.get(), Age.get(), BirthDate.get())
       tree.insert('', 'end', iid=userid, values=(ID.get(), Name.get(), Age.get(), BirthDate.get()))
    else:
        IDnumber = messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Please enter an ID number")
```

Now you can get the `userid` of the selected item when you want to delete it:

```
def DeleteData():
    try:
        userid = tree.selection()[0] ## get selected item from tree
        print(userid)
        messageDelete = messagebox.askyesno("Confirmation", "Do you want to permanently delete this record?")
        if messageDelete > 0:
                tree.delete(userid)
                Clear()
                Backend.DeleteRecord(userid)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: This works just as intended, thank you for your help!