# How to select all treeview and copy it with ctrl-c

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

1-How to select all treeview, (ctrl+a) and copy it with(ctrl-c), I found how to select multiple row.

2-is it possible to paste the sélection as an array, not as a texte, for example when I paste the sélection in Excel it will be in several columns.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree.pack()

tree['columns'] = ('one', 'two', 'three')
tree.column('#0', width=170, stretch=tk.NO)
tree.column('one', width=100, stretch=tk.NO)
tree.column('two', width=100, stretch=tk.NO)
tree.column('three', width=180, stretch=tk.NO)

tree.heading('#0', text='Name', anchor=tk.W)
tree.heading('one', text='Col1', anchor=tk.W)
tree.heading('two', text='Col2', anchor=tk.W)
tree.heading('three', text='Col3', anchor=tk.W)

tree.insert('', 'end', text='The First Item Name',values=('Col1_1', 'Col2_1', 'https://test0.test'))
tree.insert('', 'end', text='The Second Item Name',values=('Col1_2', 'Col2_2', 'https://test1.test'))
tree.insert('', 'end', text='The Third Item Name',values=('Col1_3', 'Col2_3', 'https://test2.test'))

tree.bind('<Control-a>', lambda *args: tree.selection_add(tree.get_children())) #selected all row treeview

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Do you know how to make keyboard bindings in tkinter? If not look at some tutorials and examples first. Also it is not clear what you mean by "paste the selection as an array", so be more precise and give an example if you want to get answers. You might also want to have a look at the [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @j_4321 : Sorry I changed the question I hope I have been clear enough and thank you for listening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to a `copy()` function that retrieves the values of the selected rows and put it in the clipboard. For that you can use:

- `tree.selection()` to get the selected rows iids
- `tree.item(<iid>, 'text')` to get the content of the first column
- `tree.item(<iid>, 'values')` to get the content of the other columns
- `root.clipboard_clear()` to clear the clipboard
- `root.clipboard_append(<string>)` to append text to the clipboard

2. LibreOffice (so I guess Excel too but I haven't tried) suggests to paste in different columns content separated by tabs (I think it is possible to use other kinds of separators). So the idea is to separate the values of one row by tabs and the rows by newlines.

**UPDATE**: to copy the headers as well, you can retrieve the header properties with `tree.heading("#<column number>", <option>)`, so

```
headings = [tree.heading("#{}".format(i), "text") for i in range(len(tree.cget("columns")) + 1)]
```

gives you the list of all column headers.

The full code for the `copy()` function is:

```
def copy(event):
    sel = tree.selection() # get selected items
    root.clipboard_clear()  # clear clipboard
    # copy headers
    headings = [tree.heading("#{}".format(i), "text") for i in range(len(tree.cget("columns")) + 1)]
    root.clipboard_append("\t".join(headings) + "\n")
    for item in sel:
        # retrieve the values of the row
        values = [tree.item(item, 'text')]
        values.extend(tree.item(item, 'values'))
        # append the values separated by \t to the clipboard
        root.clipboard_append("\t".join(values) + "\n")

tree.bind('<Control-c>', copy)
```

Comment: it happens to work quite well, thanks for the details.,and it works for my second question:)

Comment: a last question please, how to copy the header with the sélection